# Пунктуация в предложениях с обращениями

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте!
Возник спор, ставится ли запятая в предложении: "Доброе утро, принцесса!"

Answer (score 1):

Да, потому что "принцесса" - обращение: http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_180

Comment: Пишите более развернутые ответы, пожалуйста.  Ответы-ссылки здесь обычно удаляются.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.